# Interpolating shapefile of points to grid using Java?

Tags: raster, shapefile, java, interpolation

I am looking for a method/prog/library(java) to interpolate points from a shapefile to a grid (file). I have seen arcgis can do that but i am looking for something free.

More specific: i have shapefiles(256 or more files) with points, those points have a value of temperature. Now i want to make a file with the values of a grid converted out of this points. The interpolation method is not very important for this project. The grid would be something of 10x10.

I would like to do this in java and iterate over the files and convert them to grids. I presume there is a java library that can do this.

Comment: [Interpolation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpolate) is an *enormous* subject. I couldn't even list all the names of commonly used methods in a single comment box. There are literally hundreds, if not thousands, of free and open source solutions. Could you please do a little more research into your problem and provide some more information about what kind of data you have and what you intend to accomplish with this interpolation?

Comment: Thx for the response, I have a file with a amount of temperatures of an area. I stored those temperatures as points in a shapefile. Now i want to convert those points to a grid. The used interpolation is not very important i know there are many options but the simplest one can do the job because i don't need a high level of detail. So is was thinking to use an out of the box solution te convert them.

Comment: The grid will be something like a 10x10

Comment: If you would edit your question to include that information, I would be happy to vote to reopen.  But first you should search our site (using keywords like ["interpolation"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpolation) for existing solutions: *many* threads cover this topic). Although I find none specifically addressing Java solutions, it will help you to become familiar with the varieties of interpolation available and how to choose among them.

Comment: thx for the tip.